# How do I lock orientation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pythonista

I am trying to lock my iPad screen orientation/stop the screen rotating.
My code requires the screen/UI to be horizontal.

The only possible answer that I have found is:

```
v.present(style="full_screen", orientations=["portrait"])
```

But I still can't get the screen to lock.

I am using pythonista

Comment: Have you tried changing "portrait" to "landscape"?

Comment: @JulioP.C.  I have tried ‘landscape’ , ’portrait’ , ’vertical ’, ’horizontal’ and none of them work.

Answer (score 0):

Split-screen multitasking is [enabled by default](https://libraries.io/github/omz/PythonistaAppTemplate#customization) (since iOS 10),
and this is interfering with the setting.

The documentation explains that you should click the Requires Full Screen checkbox.

Comment: Do you know how to disable split-screen multitasking in pythonista?

Comment: The documentation explains that you should click the Requires Full Screen checkbox.

Comment: I’m not sure if I am missing something ,but I can’t find a switch/button in Pythonista to turn on “requires full screen “.
Do you know if there is a line of code that can enable this?